# jQuery find next form Element for navigation (some fields dynamically added to form)

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, navigation

I want to shift navigation from tab key to Enter key. For that I hooked keypress event of the form like

```
$("form").live("keypress", function (e) {
        if (e.keyCode == 13) {
           //here should come the code for finding next element and focusing it
          return false; // this line prevents submission of form on enter key
}
```

In this function I just have to find next form element and shift focus on that one. To get next form element I used selector from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/290535/best-way-to-find-next-form-input-element-in-jquery). But there are couple of problems with it:

1. it does not cater for select lists and any other elements than input.
2. it does not cater for hidden, disabled and readonly inputs

Besides this it uses index property of inputs to find next elements but the problem is when I alert all form elements with their indexes. they are not unique.

```
 $('form input,form select').each(function (ind, elem) {
                alert($(elem).attr("name"));
                alert($(elem).index());
            });
```

There are many form elements with 0 index. It is notable that some form elements are inserted in the DOM using JavaScript i.e after page load. How can I solve this problem?

Comment: You aren't using `index()` correctly - http://api.jquery.com/index/. `$(elem).index()` will *always* return 0 in your case.

Comment: In my opinion you shouldn't be overwriting the default browser behaviour for accessibility reasons.

Comment: Alex you are right some elements did not fire change event when focus was shifted programatically

Answer (score 0):

Something like this? You may have to tinker with the `isFocusableInput` function to get the desired effect. I've left the `console.log`s in so you can see what's happening.

```
$("form").live("keypress", function (e) {
    function isFocusableInput(el) {
        // TODO - e.g.
        var $el = $(el);
        var typeOk = !el.type || !el.type.match(/^(hidden)$/);
        return $el.is(":visible") && typeOk && !$el.is('[readonly]') && !$el.is('[disabled]');
    }
    function findFocusableInput($form, $input) {
        var inputs = $form.find(":input");
        console.log(inputs);
        var thisIdx = inputs.index($input);
        console.log("thisIdx=" + thisIdx);
        var count = 0;
        var input = null;
        // -1 because we don't want to focus the original element
        while (++count < inputs.length-1) {
            var i = (thisIdx+count)%inputs.length;
            input = inputs.eq(i)[0];
            console.log(i + "," + input.tagName);
            console.log(input);
            if (isFocusableInput(input)) {
                return input;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
    var $input = $(e.target);
    var $form = $(this);
    console.log($input);
    console.log($form);
    if (e.keyCode == 13) {
        e.stopPropagation();
        var focusableInput = findFocusableInput($form, $input);
        console.log(focusableInput);
        if (focusableInput) {
            focusableInput.focus();
        }
        return false;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

i was able to accomplish this task using following code

```
 $("form").live("keypress", function (e) {
        if (e.keyCode == 13) {
            var $fomrElements = $('form input,form select').not(":hidden").not(":disabled");
            var $nextIndex = $fomrElements.index(e.target) + 1;
            var $nextInput = $fomrElements.eq($nextIndex);
            $nextInput.focus();
            return false;
        }
    });
```