# Selecting next() input

Tags: jquery

I have the following html:

```
<div>
    <input type="text" maxlength="2" class="day-spin-month"></input>
    <span>/</span>
    <input type="text" maxlength="2" class="day-spin-day"></input>
    <span>/</span>
    <input type="text" maxlength="4" class="day-spin-year"></input>
</div>
```

I am attempting to change focus to the next input. I have it working the following 2 ways.

```
$('.day-spin-month').on('keyup', function () {
    if (this.value.length >= 2) {
       $(this).next().next().focus();
    }
});
$('.day-spin-day').on('keyup', function () {
    if (this.value.length >= 2) {
       $(this).next().next().focus();
    }
});
```

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/dan_vitch/JbQaN/1/

```
$('.day-spin-month').on('keyup', function () {
    if (this.value.length >= 2) {
       var test=$(this).next()
       var test2=  $(test).next('input');
       test2.focus();
     }
});
$('.day-spin-day').on('keyup', function () {
    if (this.value.length >= 2) {
        var test=$(this).next()
        var test2=  $(test).next('input');
        test2.focus();
    }
});
```

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/dan_vitch/JbQaN/2/

but it doesnt work this way:

```
$('.day-spin-month').on('keyup', function () {
    if (this.value.length >= 2) {
       $(this).next('input').focus();
    }
});
$('.day-spin-day').on('keyup', function () {
    if (this.value.length >= 2) {
       $(this).next('input').focus();
    }
});
```

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/dan_vitch/rJwyE/2/

I would like to use the way that is not working. I am not sure if its my selector that incorrect, or the way I understand next()

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/290535/best-way-to-find-next-form-input-element-in-jquery

Answer (score 72, accepted):

[.next()](http://api.jquery.com/next/) only looks at the next sibling Element in the DOM. IE.

```
$('.day-spin-month').next('input');
```

Won't match anything since the next sibling is a span, not an input.

[nextAll()](http://api.jquery.com/nextAll/) looks at all the next siblings, so you want:

```
$(this).nextAll('input').first().focus();
```